# Поменять DOM с помощью JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Не могу, поменять DOM с помошью "getElementById" и "innerHTML". Можете помочь как правильно сделать.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Playlist</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addSongs()
        {
            var song1 = document.getElementById("song1").innerHTML = "Blue Suede Strings, by Elvis Pagely";
            var song2 = document.getElementById(song2).innerHTML = "Great Objects on Fire, by Jerry JSON Lewis";
            var song3 = document.getElementById(song3).innerHTML = "I Code the Line, by Johnny JavaScript";
        }
        window.onload(addSongs);
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>My Awesome Playlist.</h1>
    <ul id="playlist">
        <li id="song1"></li>
        <li id="song2"></li>
        <li id="song3"></li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вопрос следует закрыть из-за опечатки.

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых вы забыли кавычки у строковых литералов `song2` и `song3`, которые использовали для поиска по `id`.

Во-вторых `js` должен находиться перед закрывающимся тегом `</body>`, так как на момент, когда `script` срабатывает элементов

```
<li id="song1"></li>
<li id="song2"></li>
<li id="song3"></li>
```

еще нет

```html
<h1>My Awesome Playlist.</h1>
<ul id="playlist">
    <li id="song1"></li>
    <li id="song2"></li>
    <li id="song3"></li>
</ul>
<script>
    assignText("song1", "Blue Suede Strings, by Elvis Pagely");
    assignText("song2", "Great Objects on Fire, by Jerry JSON Lewis");
    assignText("song3", "I Code the Line, by Johnny JavaScript");
    
    function assignText(id, text) {
      document.getElementById(id).textContent = text;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: И `innerHTML` надо заменить на `textContent`.